# jqGrid - High Memory Usage with PHP

Tags: php, memory, jqgrid, memory-management

I am loading a large amount of data (around 60,000 entries) into a jqgrid based grid (I use paging... makes for close to 3,000 pages at the number of records I am displaying per page) and I find that PHP is using a large amount of memory (over 128mb) which causes an error. I increased the amount of memory available to 256mb and it now works but I am wondering what might cause this and what can I do about it?

The code used in setting up my grid:

```
jQuery("#tlister").jqGrid({
                url:'/foo/bar/baz', // JSON data
                datatype: 'json',
                mtype: 'POST',
                colNames:['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
                colModel :[
                    {name:'a', index:'a', sorttype:'integer', width:80, editable: true, edittype:'custom', editoptions: { custom_element:custelem,custom_value:custval }},
                    {name:'b', index:'b', sorttype:'integer', width: 80, editable: false},
                    {name:'c', index:'c', width: 150, editable: false},
                    {name:'d', index:'d', width: 150, editable: false, hidden:true},
                    {name:'e', index:'e', width:200, editable: false, formatter: changeTo},
                ],
                editurl:'/foo/bar/bat',
                pager: '#pager',
                pgtext : "Page {0} of {1}",
                rowNum:20,
                loadonce: true,
                rowList:[20,40,60,80,100],
                width: 'auto',
                height: 'auto',
                caption: 'Foobar'
            });
```

---

**EDIT:**
The ajax request to /foo/bar/baz hits the database and grabs all of the entries for that grid at once. The controller calls a method in the model which returns:

```
return $this->getTable()->fetchAll()->toArray();
```

This data is then assigned to the view and the grid uses that. I guess that grabbing 60,000 records is simply expensive and that is the cause of my problem? So perhaps grabbing a limited subset of data on each grid page load would be more efficient?

Comment: You may want to show how the server side code handles the request for the data.

Comment: I updated my question to provide this.

Comment: Yes, if your grid provides paging data in the original request, limit your query to those values. E.g. only grab the first 50 records on the initial, etc.

Comment: @Jordan - Correct, the query needs to limit the results to the page size, eg 50. The jqGrid examples actually show how you can do this in MySQL. You can adapt the query to other database platforms as necessary...

Answer (score 0):

Hey I think you can use some kind of pagination that every time you change page, an ajax call is done. This way you don't need to load all records to start with.

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:pager

Comment: He mentioned he was using pagination in his question.

Comment: Yep. I am already using paging but I think the problem lies in that I am retrieving the entire set of data and then loading it into the grid, rather than retrieving only a small bit of it and then doing a new ajax request when the next set of paged data is needed. Not sure how to do that with jqgrid but I assume there will be something in the examples.

Answer (score 0):

Working example:

http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Left menu "loading data" - "Json Data"

I think this is what you should do it.